# Saving username to model in Django

Tags: python, django

I am creating a donation app that allows donors to create listings. This data is stored in a Django Model and is going to be displayed on a page. I want to save the user's username to the Django model and display it on the page. My code is down below

---

**Models.py**

```
class Donation(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  phonenumber = models.CharField(max_length=12)
  category = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  image = models.CharField(max_length=1000000)
  deliveryorpickup = models.CharField(max_length=8)
  description = models.TextField()
```

---

**Views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http.request import RAISE_ERROR
from django.http.response import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.forms import forms, inlineformset_factory
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UsernameField
from .forms import CreateUserForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from home.models  import Donation 

# Create your views here.

def index(request,*args, **kwargs):
  return render(request, "index.html", {} )



@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def dashboard(request,*args, **kwargs):
  return render(request, "dashboard.html", {} )

def register(request, ):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/dashboard/')
    else: 
        form = CreateUserForm()
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                messages.success(request, f'Your account has been successfully created, {username} ')
                return redirect('loginpage')
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, "register.html",  context )



def loginpage(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/dashboard/')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            password =request.POST.get('password')

            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('/dashboard')
            else:
        
                messages.error(request, 'Username OR password is incorrect')

        context = {}
        return render(request, 'login.html', context)

def logoutuser(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')

@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def donate(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        title = request.POST['donationtitle']
        phonenumber = request.POST['phonenumber']
        category = request.POST['category']
        image = request.POST['imagelink']
        deliveryorpickup = request.POST['deliveryorpickup']
        description = request.POST['description']
        ins = Donation(title = title, phonenumber = phonenumber, category = category, image = image, deliveryorpickup = deliveryorpickup, description = description )
        ins.save()
    return render(request,'donate.html')
```

**Forms.py (This is where the user is created)**

```
class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
  username = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=30, ) 
  email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
  first_name = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=50)
  last_name = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=50)
  

  
  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password1', 'password2',]
  #function to display errors
  def clean(self):
          cleaned_data=super().clean()
          password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
          password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')

          if User.objects.filter(username=cleaned_data["username"]).exists():
            raise ValidationError("This username is taken, please try another one")

          elif password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("2 password fields do not match")

          elif len(password1) < 8 or len(password2) < 8:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords must be at least 8 characters long")
```

Comment: what's the issue here ?

Comment: Part 1: add a foreign key field to the model pointing to your user model.

Comment: And BTW there's actually an `ImageField`.

Comment: is the issue that username do not get saved when creating a user? or that you want query that displays list of users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To associate the user with the `Donation` model, you should first add a [`ForeignKey` field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) to the model class:

```py
from django.conf import settings

class Donation(models.Model):
    ...  # your other donation fields
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
```

Once you've made this change, and run the migrations, in your **views.py** you'll pass the currently signed in user to the `Donation` model creation:

```py
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def donate(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        ins = Donation(
            title=request.POST["title"],
            ...  # all of the other fields

            user=request.user,  #  This adds the user
        )
        ins.save()
    return render(request,'donate.html')
```

#### Notes

Using `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` allows your class to [use a custom user model, or django's default user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model), based on your project's settings.

To understand what `on_delete=models.CASCADE` does, you should read [django's documentation about it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete).

Also, instead of manually passing all of the `request.POST[...]` values to the `Donation` model, I recommend that you use a [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/). It will handle errors and validation for you, as well as generate the HTML displayed in the template. Using a model form here would make your view code change to this:

```py
from django.forms import ModelForm

class DonationForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Donation
        exclude = ["user"]

@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def donate(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DonationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            donation = form.save(commit=False)
            donation.user = request.user
            donation.save()
            # Use a redirect to prevent duplicate submissions
            # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect
            return redirect(request, ...)
    else:
        form = DonationForm()
    return render(request, "donate.html", {"form": form})
```

Comment: thank you so much for such  a detailed answer, after running my migrations, I get this error in the terminal. Can you please tell me the correct answer to put for this?

Comment: You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'user' to donation without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py

Comment: Since you already have data in your database (without `user`), you can add `null=True` to the `user` field in the model, then regenerate the migration (deleting the old one) and finally running migrate again. I'll update the _models.py_ in my answer as an example.